# SGE jobs terminating after 3 hours

Tags: qsub, sungridengine, rocks

I'm used to Torque so I'm hoping that some Sun SGE guru can help. I can't figure out why my jobs are terminating at, near as I can tell 3 hours. The jobs are being submitted to an empty queue with no competition on a new install of ROCKS 6.2. Jobs shorter than 3 hours do not have any problems.

Here's the Server configuration (I think)

```
[user@machine]$ qconf -ssconf
algorithm                         default
schedule_interval                 0:0:05
maxujobs                          0
queue_sort_method                 load
job_load_adjustments              np_load_avg=0.50
load_adjustment_decay_time        0:10:30
load_formula                      slots
schedd_job_info                   false
flush_submit_sec                  1
flush_finish_sec                  10
params                            none
reprioritize_interval             0:0:0
halftime                          168
usage_weight_list                 cpu=1.000000,mem=0.000000,io=0.000000
compensation_factor               5.000000
weight_user                       0.250000
weight_project                    0.250000
weight_department                 0.250000
weight_job                        0.250000
weight_tickets_functional         0
weight_tickets_share              0
share_override_tickets            TRUE
share_functional_shares           TRUE
max_functional_jobs_to_schedule   200
report_pjob_tickets               TRUE
max_pending_tasks_per_job         50
halflife_decay_list               none
policy_hierarchy                  OFS
weight_ticket                     0.010000
weight_waiting_time               0.000000
weight_deadline                   3600000.000000
weight_urgency                    0.100000
weight_priority                   1.000000
max_reservation                   0
default_duration                  INFINITY
```

The queue configuration

```
[user@machine]$ qconf qconf -sql
all.q
[user@machine]$ qconf qconf -sq all.q
qname                 all.q
hostlist              @allhosts
seq_no                0
load_thresholds       np_load_avg=1.75
suspend_thresholds    NONE
nsuspend              1
suspend_interval      00:05:00
priority              0
min_cpu_interval      00:05:00
processors            UNDEFINED
qtype                 BATCH INTERACTIVE
ckpt_list             NONE
pe_list               make mpi mpich orte
rerun                 FALSE
slots                 1,[compute-0-0.local=4],[compute-1-0.local=4], \
                      [compute-1-1.local=4],[compute-1-2.local=4], \
                      [compute-1-3.local=4],[compute-1-4.local=4], \
                      [compute-2-0.local=4],[compute-2-1.local=4], \
                      [compute-2-2.local=4],[compute-2-4.local=4]
tmpdir                /tmp
shell                 /bin/bash
prolog                NONE
epilog                NONE
shell_start_mode      posix_compliant
starter_method        NONE
suspend_method        NONE
resume_method         NONE
terminate_method      NONE
notify                00:00:60
owner_list            NONE
user_lists            NONE
xuser_lists           NONE
subordinate_list      NONE
complex_values        NONE
projects              NONE
xprojects             NONE
calendar              NONE
initial_state         default
s_rt                  INFINITY
h_rt                  INFINITY
s_cpu                 INFINITY
h_cpu                 INFINITY
s_fsize               INFINITY
h_fsize               INFINITY
s_data                INFINITY
h_data                INFINITY
s_stack               INFINITY
h_stack               INFINITY
s_core                INFINITY
h_core                INFINITY
s_rss                 INFINITY
h_rss                 INFINITY
s_vmem                INFINITY
h_vmem                INFINITY
```

And here's a sample in progress job status.

```
[user@machine]$ qstat -j 255
==============================================================
job_number:                 255
exec_file:                  job_scripts/255
submission_time:            Mon Jul  3 11:19:07 2017
owner:                      <user>
uid:                        500
group:                      <user>
gid:                        502
sge_o_home:                 /home/<user>
sge_o_log_name:             <user>
sge_o_path:                 /home/<user>/<programDIR>/bin/linux:/home/<user>/<gitRootDIR>/<codeDIR>/bin/linux:/opt/openmpi/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/java/latest/bin:/opt/maven/bin:/opt/rocks/bin:/opt/rocks/sbin:/opt/gridengine/bin/linux-x64:/home/<user>/scripts/:/home/<user>/bin
sge_o_shell:                /bin/bash
sge_o_workdir:              <CORRECT working DIR>
sge_o_host:                 <HOSTNAME>
account:                    sge
merge:                      y
mail_options:               ae
mail_list:                  <user@domain.tld>
notify:                     FALSE
job_name:                   STDIN
stdout_path_list:           NONE:NONE:test3_w5.eo
jobshare:                   0
env_list:                   HOSTNAME=<HOSTNAME>.FQDN,SHELL=/bin/bash,TERM=xterm,HISTSIZE=1000,EGS_HOME=/home/<user>/<programDIR>/,SSH_CLIENT=172.24.56.106 56512 22,SGE_ARCH=linux-x64,SGE_CELL=default,MPICH_PROCESS_GROUP=no,QTDIR=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3,QTINC=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/include,SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0,ROCKSROOT=/opt/rocks/share/devel,ANT_HOME=/opt/rocks,USER=<user>,LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=01;05;37;41:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=01;36:*.au=01;36:*.flac=01;36:*.mid=01;36:*.midi=01;36:*.mka=01;36:*.mp3=01;36:*.mpc=01;36:*.ogg=01;36:*.ra=01;36:*.wav=01;36:*.axa=01;36:*.oga=01;36:*.spx=01;36:*.xspf=01;36:,LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/gridengine/lib/linux-x64:/opt/openmpi/lib,ROCKS_ROOT=/opt/rocks,<DEFAULT_BATCH_SYSTEM>=sge,PATH=/home/<user>/<programDIR>/bin/linux:/home/<user>/<gitRootDIR>/<codeDIR>/bin/linux:/opt/openmpi/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/java/latest/bin:/opt/maven/bin:/opt/rocks/bin:/opt/rocks/sbin:/opt/gridengine/bin/linux-x64:/home/<user>/scripts/:/home/<user>/bin,MAIL=/var/spool/mail/<user>,MAVEN_HOME=/opt/maven,<codeDIR>=/home/<user>/<gitRootDIR>/<codeDIR>/,PWD=/home/<user>/<programDIR>/dosxyznrc,JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/latest,_LMFILES_=/usr/share/Modules/modulefiles/rocks-openmpi,SGE_EXECD_PORT=537,LANG=en_US.iso885915,MODULEPATH=/usr/share/Modules/modulefiles:/etc/modulefiles,SGE_QMASTER_PORT=536,LOADEDMODULES=rocks-openmpi,SGE_ROOT=/opt/gridengine,HISTCONTROL=ignoredups,SSH_ASKPASS=/usr/libexec/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass,HOME=/home/<user>,SHLVL=2,ROLLSROOT=/opt/rocks/share/devel/src/roll,MPIHOME=/opt/openmpi,LOGNAME=<user>,CVS_RSH=ssh,QTLIB=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/lib,SSH_CONNECTION=172.24.56.106 56512 172.24.59.111 22,MODULESHOME=/usr/share/Modules,LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s,OMEGA_HOME=/home/<user>/<gitRootDIR>/<codeDIR>/omega,EGS_CONFIG=/home/<user>/<gitRootDIR>/<codeDIR>/specs/linux.conf,G_BROKEN_FILENAMES=1,OMPI_MCA_btl=self,sm,tcp,BASH_FUNC_module()=() {  eval `/usr/bin/modulecmd bash $*`
},_=/opt/gridengine/bin/linux-x64/qsub
script_file:                STDIN
usage    1:                 cpu=00:13:50, mem=833.52093 GBs, io=0.05473, vmem=1.109G, maxvmem=1.109G
scheduling info:            (Collecting of scheduler job information is turned off)
```

Comment: What is the exit code of your jobs? Any error/log messages? Dumb questions, but is it possible that they simply terminate normally because they are done by that time?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the complex has a default run time. You can inspect these w/:

```
qconf -sc | grep -e '^#' -e _rt
```

If the `default` is not `0:0:0`, then that value is enforced on the run time.

You can override this default w/:

```
qsub -l s_rt=8:0:0 ...
```

for 8 hours, for example. Set `s_rt` or `h_rt` (soft/hard limits) based on which is set at the complex level.